# Prove that $\int_a^b f\,dx= 0$ given $f(r)= 0$ for all $r \in \mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is a nonnegative Riemann integrable function on $[a,b]$ satisfying $f(r) = 0$ for all $r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [a,b]$. Prove that $\int_a^b f\,dx = 0$.

Since all rational function values give $f = 0$, does $f(x) = 0$? 
If yes, how can I show that formally?

If no, how would I approach this proof?

Comment: For the first question, this would happen if $f$ is continuous. Else, consdier ${\bf 1}_{\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q}$, the indicator function of the irrationals.

Comment: You cannot conclude that $f(x)= 0$ for all $x$. However, note that if $f(x_0)>0$ for some $x_0\in [a,b]$, then $x_0$ must be a point of discontinuity of $f$ (why?). What do you know about the set of points where a Riemann integrable function is discontinuous?

Comment: Hint: If $f$ is Riemann integrable, then the value of the integral can be approximated as closely as you wish by any Riemann Sum corresponding to a partition of $[a,b]$ with sufficiently small norm.

Answer (score 2):

A more careful phrasing of my comment:

Let $f$ be Riemann Integrable on $[a,b]$ with $I=\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$.  Then for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ so that if $\{x_0,\ldots, x_n\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ with $\max\limits_{1\le j\le n}(x_j-x_{j-1}) <\delta$, then
$$
\Bigl| I-\sum_{j=1}^n f(t_j)(x_j-x_{j-1})\Bigr|< \epsilon
$$
for any choice of $t_1,\ldots t_n$ with $t_j\in [x_{j-1},x_j]$ for each admissible $j$.

Now note that given *any* partition of $[a,b]$, you can choose tags $t_i$ so that the corresponding Riemann sum for your function has the value $0$.

Comment: I'll point out here that the hypothesis that $f$ be nonnegative is not necessary.